# How to overlap border with image and add shadow effect on the border?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I tried to overlap the border with an image inside but i found it unable to apply while i saw some application are able to do so. Any idea?

[image: Something like this]

```
   <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="20,20" Height="120" Width="410" >
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Canvas>
                                            <Image Margin="-30,0,0,45" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding Path=ListboxImage}" Width="100" Height="150" />
                                        </Canvas>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock Margin="135,8" Width="300" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=ListboxName}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Margin="150,0,0,8" Width="300" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=ListboxDescription}" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
```

While i tried to add some shadow effect to the border.

```
<Border>
    <Border.Effect>
    .......
    </Border.Effect>

</Border>
```

but it seem to be doesn't support the effect. 
+ I found some forum said that they took off the effect due to performance~
Any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I find it for you man... Try this you can get overlapped image in the border

```
       <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding alldata}" Height="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   Margin="12,160,0,0" Name="listBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="438" Background="Black">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White">
                <StackPanel Height="250" Orientation="Vertical" Name="stackPanel1" Width="400" >


                    <Border Margin="30,40,0,120" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White">
                            <Canvas Height="100">
                                <TextBlock Text="Catalogue" Margin="160,50">   </TextBlock>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Border>

                        <Image Height="150" Width="160" Margin="-400,-400,-200,0" Source="{Binding image}">

                        </Image>


                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

in mainpage.cs add the code

```
      Uri uri = new      Uri("http://d1mu9ule1cy7bp.cloudfront.net/2012/media/catalogues/47/pages/p_"+ i +"/thump.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
            ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
            Image image = new Image();

alldata data = new alldata(){image = img.source, text = "catalogue"};


  public class alldata
 {
  public imagesource image
  public string text
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying =) 
I found tat the solution is not tat flexible >< 
Seem like hard code more than functioning way =( 
Anyway Thanks for your help ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a rectangle and image inside a stack

```
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <border>
              <rectangle height="50">
              <textblock text={}>
              </rectangle>
              </border>
                  <Image Margin="-30,0,0,45"  height = "75"/>
          </Stackpanel>
```

Try to align the margin of image to be in the left of stackpanel and the rectangle height   should be less than the image height.Try to reduce the corner radius of rectangle this also helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying. 
I tried with ur solution. But the textblock seem to be unsupport inside the rectangle.